# Throwing an error for multiple records in JSON

Tags: angular, angular8, ngfor

In my JSON I have multiple records, but in browser it is only showing one record. I tried using NgFor to repeat the same, but I am getting an error.

Here is my first child html

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="organization">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Organization Name </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="showInfo(element)"> {{element.organizationName}}
     </td>
 </ng-container>
```

Here is the ts for the first child

```
showInfo(rowData) {
    let dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig = {
      width: '850px',
      data:rowData
    }
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalPopupTrialTypeComponent, dialogConfig);
}
```

Here is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "regionName": "EMEA",
    "regionCurrency": "USD",
    "orgnazationName": "XYZ",
    "orgnazationSubName": "Miller"
    "Department": [
      {
        "DepartmentName": "Main",
        "FirstName": "David",
        "LastName": "Brown",
        "Band": 2,
        "Salary": 10000.00
      },
      {
        "DepartmentName": "Main 1", 
        "FirstName": "Marry",
        "LastName": "Brown",
        "Band": 2,
        "Salary": 10000.00
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my ts code:

```
export class ModalPopupTrialTypeComponent implements OnInit {
  public rowData: any;
  private unsubscribe: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalPopupTrialTypeComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public Modaldata) {  
      this.rowData = Modaldata;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Modal Data',this.rowData);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe.forEach(sb => sb.unsubscribe());
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Department Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Band</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>   
        <tr *ngFor="let item of rowData.Department" >
            <td>{{item.DepartmentName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Band}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Salary}}</td>
        </tr >        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

After adding .department in the NGFor I am not getting error but the it was showing only one record not multiple record

Comment: have you tried `*ngFor="let item of rowData.Department`. Looks like it's what you are trying to do

Comment: @JorgeMussato yes I have tried now I am not getting error but  am not getting the multiple value

Comment: try adding outside the table tag `{{rowData | json}}` and post what shows in screen here. Because that `JSON` in your post may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over **`rowData.department`** which has the necessary attributes not rowData,

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of rowData.department" >
```

Comment: i tried like above 

*ngFor="let item of rowData.department" but still I am getting only one data

Comment: I am not getting error but I am not getting error but I am not getting the value also

Comment: can you please help me still the data was not showing

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the data in console.log has multiple data in the department array.

Comment: I meant the console.log inside ngOninit. is it showing correct data as what you expect

Comment: in console.log it was showing only one record but in json I have 2 records

Comment: that means the html part of <tr> is fine. log the rowdata value inside showInfo method i think this element has only one record and hence this is happening